# scrollTop a div when user starts scrolling, and then let users free to scroll

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, scrollto

I have 2 divs on a webpage.
First div is #pattern, and the other div is #top.

When the user arrives on my webpage, the two divs are visibile.
as soon as the user starts scrolling, I want the "#top" div to scrollto top.
I managed to achieve this, but once it's done, i want the user to be abble to start scrolling again, I just want the scrollto animation to appear once, when user scrolls for the first time.

I'm using jquery.scrollTo plugin.

I tried using a flag, but it's not working...

Here is my html :

```
<div id="pattern">
</div>

<div id="top">
</div>
```

My css :

```
#pattern {
    height: 600px; 
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue
}

#top {
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

and my Jquery :

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){    
    var flag=0 ;

    if((flag==0) && $(window).scrollTop()>10){ 
        $(window).scrollTo('#top', 800);
        flag=1;
    }    
});
```

Here is JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w8mgnmfe/

Comment: Putting `var flag = 0;` outside the scroll handler would probably be the easiest fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn the event [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) when you do the scrolling:

```
$(window).on('scroll.mynamespace',function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
        $(window).off('scroll.mynamespace');
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top});
    }

});
```

Note: I have updated it to use no plugins. Also change `mynamespace` to something more meaningful like scrollToDiv or whatever makes sense to you. This ensures that you only turn that event off.

If you want to reactivate it:

```
var autoScrolled = false;
var scrollBoundary = 10;

$(window).on('scroll.mynamespace',function() {

    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (!autoScrolled && windowTop > scrollBoundary) {
        autoScrolled = true;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top});
    } else if(autoScrolled && windowTop <= scrollBoundary) {
         autoScrolled = false;
    }

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/b5ybs6xg/1/

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I get an error  in my console : "TypeError: window.scrollTop is not a function"

Comment: @mmdwc please try now and check the fiddle - also it uses no plugins

Comment: Wrong fiddle link - try now

Comment: there's a missing $ before (window).scrollTop() > 10) {

Comment: Targeted unbinding like that's pretty neat. Upvoting for something you don't see every day.

Comment: @DominicTobias Tobias is it possible when I scroll up my page again, then window position is 0, to activate the scrollTo again ?

Comment: @mmdwc I see you have a solution, I also added one too (basically the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by putting the flag outside my scroll event...

here is the complete code :

```
var flag=0 ;

$(window).on('scroll',function(){    


    if((flag==0) && $(window).scrollTop()>10){ 
        $(window).scrollTo('#top', 800);
        flag=1;
    }    

        if($(window).scrollTop()==0){ 
        flag=0;
    }   
});
```